# Flask Restful reqparse add_argument type for binary

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have created a rest api using Flask Restful and used reqparse to fetch data passed on with POST call.

So far I could fetch data that are passed as raw in Postman. What should be the type to be included in add_argument of reqparse if I want to use binary in Postman?

Current code:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse

def post(self):
    parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
    parser.add_argument('dataUrl')
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

If create parser in next way:

```
upload_parser = server.api.parser()
upload_parser.add_argument('', location='data',
                           type=bytes, required=True)
```

You will receive error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
I tried to change type= to FileStorage, bytes, bytearray, but nothing helped.

If instead of data use any location from https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/flask_restplus/reqparse.html you will receive an error about missing parameters.

Comment: Update 1.
After inspecting of flask_restplus code I managed to find a workaround how to receive and work with binary data.
1) chande name in add_argument to "data"
2) go to /..../site-packages/flask_restplus/reqparse.py (i.e. location where flask_restplus installed) and add lines 

if self.location == 'data':
                return {'data': value}

to def source function right after value = getattr(request, self.location, MultiDict()).

After this changes I managed to send via postman binary file and receive it in my route.

Answer (score 0):

Use flask_restful.inputs.boolean AND set its default value (otherwise it would not work). Example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse, inputs

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('dataUrl', type=inputs.boolean, default=False)

@app.route('/<string:dataUrl>')
def post(self, dataUrl):
    data = parser.parse_args()
    return data
```